# How do I manually add a permission for a Static Block to the Database?

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions

My Static Blocks aren't displaying in my cms pages when I add them to the content tab with

> {{block type=”cms/block” block_id=”product_view_block_3”}}

BUT it's not showing. Apparently I have to add the Static Block I want to use however my Admin Interface isn't working because of a Theme I use that I have ALWAYS had issues with SO I can't get into permissions because it's just a blank screen

**Responsive Admin Template by CMSMART** if anyone is interested (It **REALLY SUCKS**)
We are just waiting to upgrade to Magento 2 so we can ditch the Admin Theme WITH EXTREME PREJUDICE ... but I digress

Anyway
I've found the permission list in the Database BUT I can't find the name of my static block - this would normally be added by the Magento Admin Interface
SO
How can I add it manually (My static block identifier is product_view_block_3)
I tried 'product_view_block_3/view' but nothing happened....have I got the 'block_name' wrong?

I also tried Mage_Core_Block_Template because it displayed this name with hints switched on but again nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like problem connected with permissions. You can add permission for all cms blocks through database or admin panel.

1) through DB:

```
INSERT INTO `permission_block` (`block_name`, `is_allowed`) VALUES
('cms/block', 1);
```

2) through admin panel: System -> Permissions -> Blocks -> Add New Block -> Block Name -> cms/block

Comment: 'cms/block'   -  That's what I was looking for


-Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think block type is not define from admin side.

Goto " **System -> Permissions -> Blocks** "  and add new block type.

I think this may help you.

Comment: Yeah I know that but as I explained - The screen <System -> Permissions -> Blocks> doesn't render because of the stupid admin theme that never works because of CM[NOT SO]SMARTs oops! programming.